# ' getValues() ' collecting only one value when trying to remove empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script

My idea is to remove the diacricts from the values and send them to Column B, but also send the original values to Column C of the spreadsheet.

Column A on Spreadsheet:

```
ábéécÓ
Á
ábéécÓ
Á
```

My code:

```
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
  {'base':'A', 'letters':'\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'},
  {'base':'AA','letters':'\uA732'},
  {'base':'AE','letters':'\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'},
  {'base':'AO','letters':'\uA734'},
  {'base':'AU','letters':'\uA736'},
  {'base':'AV','letters':'\uA738\uA73A'},
  {'base':'AY','letters':'\uA73C'},
  {'base':'B', 'letters':'\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'},
  {'base':'C', 'letters':'\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'},
  {'base':'D', 'letters':'\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0'},
  {'base':'DZ','letters':'\u01F1\u01C4'},
  {'base':'Dz','letters':'\u01F2\u01C5'},
  {'base':'E', 'letters':'\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'},
  {'base':'F', 'letters':'\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'},
  {'base':'G', 'letters':'\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'},
  {'base':'H', 'letters':'\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'},
  {'base':'I', 'letters':'\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'},
  {'base':'J', 'letters':'\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'},
  {'base':'K', 'letters':'\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'},
  {'base':'L', 'letters':'\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'},
  {'base':'LJ','letters':'\u01C7'},
  {'base':'Lj','letters':'\u01C8'},
  {'base':'M', 'letters':'\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'},
  {'base':'N', 'letters':'\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'},
  {'base':'NJ','letters':'\u01CA'},
  {'base':'Nj','letters':'\u01CB'},
  {'base':'O', 'letters':'\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'},
  {'base':'OI','letters':'\u01A2'},
  {'base':'OO','letters':'\uA74E'},
  {'base':'OU','letters':'\u0222'},
  {'base':'OE','letters':'\u008C\u0152'},
  {'base':'oe','letters':'\u009C\u0153'},
  {'base':'P', 'letters':'\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'},
  {'base':'Q', 'letters':'\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'},
  {'base':'R', 'letters':'\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'},
  {'base':'S', 'letters':'\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'},
  {'base':'T', 'letters':'\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'},
  {'base':'TZ','letters':'\uA728'},
  {'base':'U', 'letters':'\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'},
  {'base':'V', 'letters':'\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'},
  {'base':'VY','letters':'\uA760'},
  {'base':'W', 'letters':'\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'},
  {'base':'X', 'letters':'\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'},
  {'base':'Y', 'letters':'\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'},
  {'base':'Z', 'letters':'\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'},
  {'base':'a', 'letters':'\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'},
  {'base':'aa','letters':'\uA733'},
  {'base':'ae','letters':'\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'},
  {'base':'ao','letters':'\uA735'},
  {'base':'au','letters':'\uA737'},
  {'base':'av','letters':'\uA739\uA73B'},
  {'base':'ay','letters':'\uA73D'},
  {'base':'b', 'letters':'\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'},
  {'base':'c', 'letters':'\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'},
  {'base':'d', 'letters':'\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'},
  {'base':'dz','letters':'\u01F3\u01C6'},
  {'base':'e', 'letters':'\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'},
  {'base':'f', 'letters':'\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'},
  {'base':'g', 'letters':'\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'},
  {'base':'h', 'letters':'\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'},
  {'base':'hv','letters':'\u0195'},
  {'base':'i', 'letters':'\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'},
  {'base':'j', 'letters':'\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'},
  {'base':'k', 'letters':'\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'},
  {'base':'l', 'letters':'\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'},
  {'base':'lj','letters':'\u01C9'},
  {'base':'m', 'letters':'\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'},
  {'base':'n', 'letters':'\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'},
  {'base':'nj','letters':'\u01CC'},
  {'base':'o', 'letters':'\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'},
  {'base':'oi','letters':'\u01A3'},
  {'base':'ou','letters':'\u0223'},
  {'base':'oo','letters':'\uA74F'},
  {'base':'p','letters':'\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'},
  {'base':'q','letters':'\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'},
  {'base':'r','letters':'\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'},
  {'base':'s','letters':'\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'},
  {'base':'t','letters':'\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'},
  {'base':'tz','letters':'\uA729'},
  {'base':'u','letters': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'},
  {'base':'v','letters':'\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'},
  {'base':'vy','letters':'\uA761'},
  {'base':'w','letters':'\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'},
  {'base':'x','letters':'\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'},
  {'base':'y','letters':'\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'},
  {'base':'z','letters':'\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'}
];

var diacriticsMap = {};
for (var i=0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap .length; i++){
  var letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap [i].letters;
  for (var j=0; j < letters.length ; j++){
    diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap [i].base;
  }
}

function Looping() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('remove_diacritics'),
      range,
      values_array; 
  range = sheet.getRange('A1:A');
  var loop = range.getValues().flat().filter(e =>  e);
  sheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue(loop);
  var new_values = [];
  for (var key of loop) {
    var newText = key.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, function(a){ 
      return diacriticsMap[a] || a;
    });
    new_values.push(newText);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(new_values);
}
```

Column B and C on Spreadsheet return after run the code:

```
abeecO  ábéécÓ
```

Expected Result in Column B and C on Spreadsheet:

```
abeecO  ábéécÓ
A       Á
abeecO  ábéécÓ
A       Á
```

I also tried create a loop using but it didn't work:

```
var loop = range.getValues().filter(function(array){
    return array != ''
})
```

What am I doing wrong that all four values are not collected?

Comment: are you trying to combine the words from column A and return them to just cell C1? or you want it to be aligned with your column A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your 1st submitted quesiton, you are trying to put an array of `var loop = range.getValues().flat().filter(e =>  e);` to the sheet with `sheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue(loop);`. In this case, 1st element of the array `loop` is put to the cell "C1". I thought that this is the reason of your issue. And also, at `var loop = range.getValues().flat().filter(e =>  e);`, 2 dimensional array is converted to 1 dimensional array. In this case, it it is required to modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      range = sheet.getRange('A1:A');
      var loop = range.getValues().flat().filter(e =>  e);
      sheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue(loop);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      range = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow());
      var loop = range.getValues().filter(([a]) => a.toString() != "");
      sheet.getRange(1, 3, loop.length, 1).setValues(loop);
    ```
  - By this modification, the filtered values of `loop` are put to the column "C".
- When I saw your latest question, the same situation as the above situation can be seen. I think that it is required to modify your latest script like the above one. But, from your showing sample input and output situations, I thought that when the cell value of column "A" is empty, it might be required to put the empty.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify `Looping()` as follows.

```js
function Looping() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('remove_diacritics');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var loop = range.getValues();
  var new_values = [];
  for (var key of loop) {
    var value = key[0];
    if (value != "") {
      var newText = value.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, function (a) {
        return diacriticsMap[a] || a;
      });
      new_values.push([newText, value]);
    } else {
      new_values.push(["", ""]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, new_values.length, new_values[0].length).setValues(new_values);
}
```

Or, you can also the following modified script.

```js
function Looping() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('remove_diacritics');
  var values = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var new_values = values.map(([v]) => [v.toString() != "" ? v.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, a => diacriticsMap[a] || a) : "", v]);
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, new_values.length, new_values[0].length).setValues(new_values);
}
```

- When these modified scripts are used, your expected result is obtained. And, in this modification, when the cell value of column "A" is empty, the empty values are put to the columns "B" and "C".
- If you want to skip the empty rows of the column "A", please modify `var loop = range.getValues();` in the above 2 scripts as follows.

  ```
    function Looping() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('remove_diacritics');
      var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow());
      var loop = range.getValues().filter(([a]) => a.toString() != "");
      var new_values = [];
      for (var key of loop) {
        var newText = key[0].replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, function (a) {
          return diacriticsMap[a] || a;
        });
        new_values.push([newText, key[0]]);
      }
      sheet.getRange(1, 2, new_values.length, new_values[0].length).setValues(new_values);
    }
  ```
- Or

  ```
    function Looping() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('remove_diacritics');
      var values = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
      var new_values = values.flatMap(([v]) => v.toString() != "" ? [[v.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, a => diacriticsMap[a] || a), v]] : []);
      sheet.getRange(1, 2, new_values.length, new_values[0].length).setValues(new_values);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

#### Getting all of column one

Using ranges like `A1:A` is not useful because it returns nulls from lastrow to maxrows which need to be filtered out which is just a waste of time.

```
function Looping() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}

Execution log
5:43:28 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:43:27 PM  Info    [["ábéécÓ"],["Á"],["ábéécÓ"],["Á"]]//2D array
5:43:29 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Original Data:

| A |
| --- |
| ábéécÓ |
| Á |
| ábéécÓ |
| Á |

Comment: Cooper, good night, sorry for delivering a question with lack of details, I put the complete code for full view of the case!

If by chance you can take a look and if you want to put some more details in the answer, but in this current form of the answer I already understand the idea of its format!